# CSS3 gradient background with unwanted white space at bottom

Tags: css, whitespace, gradient

I am having a great deal of difficulty with getting rid of the white space at the bottom when I apply a CSS3 gradient and the content has insufficient height for a scrollbar.

Such as here:  http://womancareolympia.webs.com/

I have tried playing with setting both html and body heights to 100% or auto.  I am able to make the gradient go to the bottom this way, but then when content requires a scrollbar, the content flows past the gradient.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Add `min-height: 100%` to `body`.
- Remove all instances of `padding-top` from `body` (or otherwise set it to `0`).
- Set `top: 129px` on `#fw-container`.
- Set `margin-bottom: 110px` on `#fw-container`.
- Add `overflow: hidden` to `#fw-foottext`.

*(tested in Chrome+Firefox only)*

I do think you should redesign your CSS **to not use** stuff like `top: 100px` and `margin-top: -50px` all over the place. There's just no reason for it.

Comment: Fixed!  Thank you so much, I have had this problem everywhere!

Comment: Should I use padding instead of margin or top/left?  I am being forced to used a template and some builder utility and the only thing I can do is ADD my own CSS.  I can't edit the pre-existing CSS or HTML.

Comment: Well in that case, maybe it's not such a bad solution after all. I can imagine not being able to change around the HTML or edit the existing CSS would be very crippling. What you have works fine, it's just a little inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This can be resolved by adding the following properties to the body element (where the linear gradient has been defined)

```
 body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right bottom, 
        var(--clr-primary-100) 0%,  // Random colors
        var(--clr-primary-900) 100%
    ); // Linear gradient
    background-size: cover;      // Add these properties to your body tag
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you face any problems.