# Make body have 100% of the browser height

Tags: html, css, height

I want to make `body` have 100% of the browser height. Can I do that using CSS?

I tried setting `height: 100%`, but it doesn't work.

I want to set a background color for a page to fill the entire browser window, but if the page has little content I get a ugly white bar at the bottom.

Comment: [CSS3 Viewport-percentage lengths](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25829844/2680216)

Answer (score 1409, accepted):

Try setting the height of the html element to 100% as well.

```
html, 
body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Body looks to its parent (HTML) for how to scale the dynamic property, so the HTML element needs to have its height set as well.

However the content of body will probably need to change dynamically.
Setting min-height to 100% will accomplish this goal.

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks, this seem to remove the white bar on short pages, but now on pages which height exceeds the browser window height I get a 20px white bar at the bottom :|

Comment: ok I found out! it works if I add html,body{min-height:100%;} :D

Comment: Make a website with this as the only text on it. This is beyond useful for beginning web designers.

Comment: Note: if you use the `body {min-height}` version then you cannot use `.body-child{height: 100%}` trick.

Comment: Why appear always the scroll bar?
Down in the answare there is solution without this problem. But why  min-height have this problem?

Comment: I had this white-bar-at-the-bottom-issue as well when trying this out yersterday. Setting an according padding to the body (padding: 10px; in my case) solved the issue. HTH

Comment: For all the people posting "It doesn't work for me". This is a known working solution. If you are having trouble, then I would guess that it is becuase of css in your application.

Comment: best answer is with CSS3, using `vh` ->  `body { height: 100vh }` - check answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25829844/2680216

Comment: @bFunc I have this chrome issue to.
html{height:100%;} body {height:auto} do the job.

Comment: min-height: 100% is not enough. If the page is embedded in an iframe it fails. https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/jbmaded2/

Comment: I think that's a very specific scenario, although the iframe really shouldn't make a difference. Maybe you are seeing a browser inconsistency ?

Comment: @AdrianoResende The problem with that is that on mobile browsers, the height of the address bar is included in the 100vh value. This leaves part of the body below the fold. With 100% height, you can exclude the address bar's height, so the entire body is visible.

Comment: This method also disables the ability scroll. Folks use height: 100vh like the answer below. @bodyofheat please accept the below answer as it is now the better way of achieving this.

Comment: FWIW - This did not work for me when trying to resolve this issue in MS Edge.

Comment: `html { height: 100%; }`. This 100% of what?

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin 100% of the current document height aka the size of the browser.

Comment: Suggest using the `display: table` method lower down. This approach means children of the `body` cannot use `height: 100%` to fill the page.

Comment: This is so outdated and won't fit most viewports and layouts cause it is not dynamic. For example, try to zoom your page using it in Google Chrome and it won't stretch. [That answer is a bit better.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25829844/8524922)

Comment: @Beyondo I agree, using view port based lengths is superior in most use cases. This answer is very old.

Answer (score 287):

As an alternative to setting both the `html` and `body` element's heights to `100%`, you could also use viewport-percentage lengths.

> [**5.1.2. Viewport-percentage lengths: the ‘vw’, ‘vh’, ‘vmin’, ‘vmax’ units**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)
>
> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block. When the height or width of the initial containing block is changed, they are scaled accordingly.

In this instance, you could use the value `100vh` - which is the height of the viewport.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dkdsfddz/)

```
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This is supported in most modern browsers - [support can be found here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: Besides the fact that this is dead simple, it's also good that we adopt new practices.

Comment: @niaster I definitely agree. Browser support has already improved since I posted this answer as well :)

Comment: @incarnate Yeah.. too bad it isn't :) It looks like the last time the OP was online was in 7/11/11 (the date the question was asked..) So I doubt that will change.

Comment: Not sure why we need to start "adopting new practices" when the old practice works fine.  There's no advantage to doing this:  the code is not smaller, nor does it perform any better, and there are still browsers out there that don't support vw/vh.

Comment: @BentOnCoding According to [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), it works on a majority of mobile devices. I've never had any problems with it. Which devices/versions are your referring to?

Comment: On Apple tablets on Safari, this method is really buggy.

Comment: Chrome user agent stylesheet adds an 8px margin to body by default (not sure about other browsers), so I had to also add `margin: 0;` to avoid a persistent vertical scroll bar to the right.

Comment: @cimmanon, the body height 100% didn't work for me with bootstrap. This solution worked.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

Comment: not working when you have another child which is bigger
http://jsfiddle.net/dkdsfddz/266/

Comment: This solution results in extra scroll on mobile (Chrome, Android) because it calculates viewport height without taking the toolbar into account.

Comment: Exactly as @int_index is saying, this method will cause your page to gain an unnecessary vertical scrollbar in some browsers. Follow this answer instead https://stackoverflow.com/a/38908284/1860149 for a cross-browser solution.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.  All my other elements are absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 138):

If you have a background image then you will want to set this instead:

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

This ensures that your body tag is allowed to continue growing when the content is taller than the viewport and that the background image continues to repeat/scroll/whatever when you start scrolling down.

Remember if you have to support IE6 you will need to find a way to wedge in `height:100%` for body, IE6 treats `height` like `min-height` anyway.

Comment: Also works when there is a global flexbox right under body (body > #flexbox-wrapper)

Comment: This is the correct answer, as the accepted answer will not grow as content gets longer than a single screen.

Comment: Thank you so much, Angry Dan, that ugly white space at the bottom of my site is gone!

Comment: Of course, since this question was posed, view port based dimensions became a Thing. So now you can just do `body{min-height: 100vh}`

Comment: You also need `body { height: auto; }` for scrollbars to not be shown in FireFox. other than that, works perfectly.

Comment: This didn't work for me in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

Comment: I finally found an answer on this page that actually worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38908284/470749

Answer (score 90):

If you want to keep the margins on the body and don't want scroll bars, use the following css:

```
html { height:100%; }
body { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
```

Setting  `body {min-height:100%}`  will give you scroll bars.

See demo at http://jsbin.com/aCaDahEK/2/edit?html,output .

Comment: Thank you for the only working answer :) I assume 'absolute' made it work

Comment: Works well for me in Firefox without scrollbars, thank you. The accepted answer does not.

Comment: @Andrew Oddly enough, this gives scroll-bars in FireFox. What you need however to the accepted answer is `height: auto;` in the `body` clause as well for scrollbars to now pop up.

Comment: @Torxed I still get scroll bars in FireFox with this too. Adding the auto setting to height didn't seem to work for me :(

Comment: This didn't work for me in Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

Comment: I don't think setting the entire body's position as absolute is the right way of doing things.

Comment: @AnshSaini May I ask why?

Answer (score 73):

After testing various scenarios, I believe this is the best solution:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

It is dynamic in that the `html` and the `body` elements will expand automatically if their contents overflow.  I tested this in the latest version of Firefox, Chrome, and IE 11.

See the full fiddle here (for you table haters out there, you can always change it to use a div):

https://jsfiddle.net/71yp4rh1/9/

---

With that being said, there are **several issues with the answers posted here**.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Using the above CSS will cause the html and the body element to NOT automatically expand if their contents overflow as shown here:

https://jsfiddle.net/9vyy620m/4/

As you scroll, notice the repeating background?  This is happening because the body element's height has NOT increased due to its child table overflowing.  Why doesn't it expand like any other block element?  I'm not sure.  I think browsers handle this incorrectly.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Setting a min-height of 100% on the body as shown above causes other problems.  If you do this, you cannot specify that a child div or table take up a percentage height as shown here:

https://jsfiddle.net/aq74v2v7/4/

Hope this helps someone.  I think browsers are handling this incorrectly.  I would expect the body's height to automatically adjust growing larger if its children overflow.  However, that doesn't seem to happen when you use 100% height and 100% width.

Comment: I tried all of the high-voted answers on this page, but none worked. This one did!

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one.

The `height: 100vh` is not a solution neither. Setting your top container to be `100vh` high and `100vw` might cause problems if the container has scrollbars - then it will larger than it should be (and might cause the scrollbars to be visible unnecessarily).

The `height: 100vh` also caused problems for us on newer Android devices (e.g. Xiaomi Mi 9 with Android 9), where the container would be larger than the screen itself, and would make unnecessary vertical scrollbar to the document body.

Comment: I think body min-height and its child height problem is because you can not calculate the % value of dynamic property as min-height. Cause min-height is dynamic not static.

Comment: After 2 hours, this was the only solution that worked for me. Thank You!

Comment: also working correctly when you have eg. Dev Tools open and 100 vh is not available +1

Comment: That's awesome. I aswell tried all of the accepted answers, none of them helped as the content was way to large then the actual size.

Comment: Setting the `height` to 100% on the html and body effectively locks the body's height to the height of the window. This behavior is absolutely correct. Why? Read on. Percentage heights are based on the screen pixel height of the parent element. Imagine a scenario where an element with a percentage `height` is appended to a parent with only a percentage `min-height` set. If the element causes the parent's screen pixel height to grow, you can see why that could be a problem. An infinite loop. Browser's correctly avoid the infinite loop. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 34):

```
html, body
{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 30):

A better solution with modern CSS

```
html, body{ 
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: How does this offer anything different over the existing answers?

Comment: I have tried others also, but did not work for me. This one worked, so it can be a solution to someone needy. @cimmanon

Comment: I have to say this one works for me other than other high vote answers. `overflow: auto` here do the magic. Btw I use Chrome.

Comment: Only option (I've found) which allows for overflowing content to resize the height.

Comment: this is perfect answer if you're using float

Answer (score 22):

What I use on the start of literally every CSS file I use is the following:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;

    padding: 0;

    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

The margin of 0 ensures that the HTML and BODY elements aren't being auto-positioned by the browser to have some space to the left or right of them.

The padding of 0 ensures that the HTML and BODY elements aren't automatically pushing everything inside them down or right because of browser defaults.

The width and height variants are set to 100% to ensure that the browser doesn't resize them in anticipation of actually having an auto-set margin or padding, with min and max set just in case some weird, unexplainable stuff happens, though you probably dont need them.

This solution also means that, like I did when I first started on HTML and CSS several years ago, you won't have to give your first `<div>` a `margin:-8px;` to make it fit in the corner of the browser window.

---

Before I posted, I looked at my other fullscreen CSS project and found that all I used there was just `body{margin:0;}` and nothing else, which has worked fine over the 2 years I've been working on it.

Hope this detailed answer helps, and I feel your pain. In my eyes, it is dumb that browsers should set an invisible boundary on the left and sometimes top side of the body/html elements.

Comment: Could you explain please, what is the possible purpose of `width: 100%` for body and html elements? Yes, I understand, that from practical point of view, `body { margin: 0; }` should be enough in most cases. I just want to understand more thoroughly.

Answer (score 8):

### CSS Height That Works in Both Modern and Legacy Browsers

**Most of the other solutions posted here will **not** work well in legacy browsers!** And some of the code people posted will cause a *nasty overflow of text beyond 100% height* in modern browsers where text flows past background colors, which is bad design! So please try my code solution instead.

The CSS code below should support flexible web page *height settings* correctly in all known browsers, past and present:

```
html {
    height: 100%; /* Fallback CSS for IE 4-6 and older browsers. Note: Without this setting, body below cannot achieve 100% height. */
    height: 100vh;/* Overrides 100% height in modern HTML5 browsers and uses the viewport's height. Only works in modern HTML5 browsers */
}

body {
    height: auto; /* Allows content to grow beyond the page without overflow */
    width: auto; /* Allows content to grow beyond the page without overflow */
    min-height: 100%; /* Starts web page with 100% height. Fallback for IE 4-6 and older browsers */
    min-height: 100vh;/* Starts web page with 100% height. Uses the viewport's height. Only works in modern HTML5 browsers */
    overflow-y: scroll;/* Optional: Adds an empty scrollbar to the right margin in case content grows vertically, creating a scrollbar.  Allows for better width calculations, as the browser pre-calculates width before scrollbar appears, avoiding page content shifting.*/
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background:yellow;/* FOR TESTING: Next add a large block of text or content to your page and make sure this background color always fills the screen as your content scrolls off the page. If so, this works. You have 100% height with flexible content! */
}
```

NOTES ON THE CODE ABOVE

In many older, as well as newer browsers, if you do not set 100% height on the `<html>` selector, body will never achieve 100% height! So that is critical here.

The new viewport units ("vh") are redundant on the `body` selector and not necessary as long as you have set `html` selector to a height of either `100%` or `100vh`. The reason is the `body` always derives its values from the `html` parent. The exception is a few very old browsers from the past, so its best to set some height value for the body.

Some modern browsers using  the `body` selector will not know how to inherit the viewport height directly. So again, always set your `html` selector to 100% height! You can still use "vh" units in `body` to bypass the parent `html` value and get its property dimensions directly from the viewport in most modern browsers, however. But again, its optional if the parent or root `html` selector has `100%` height, which `body` will always inherit correctly.

Notice I've set `body` to `height:auto`, not `height:100%`. This collapses the `body` element around content initially so it can grow as content grows. **You do NOT want to set `body` `height` and `width` to `100%`, or specific values** as that limits content to the body's current *visual* dimensions, not its *scrollable* dimensions. Anytime you assign body `height:100%`, as soon as content text moves beyond the browser's height, it will overflow the container and thus any backgrounds assigned to the original viewport height, creating an ugly visual! **`height:auto` is your best friend in CSS!**

But you still want body to default to 100% height, right? That is where `min-height:100%` works wonders! It will not only allow your body element to default to 100% height, but this works in even the oldest browsers! But best of all, it allows your background to fill 100% and yet stretch farther down as content with height:auto grows vertically.

Using `overflow:auto` properties are not needed if you set `height:auto` on the `body`. That tells the page to let content expand height to any dimension necessary, even beyond the viewport's height, if it needs to and content grows longer than the viewport page display. It will not break out of the `body` dimensions. And it does allow scrolling as needed. `overflow-y:scroll` allows you to add an empty scrollbar to the right of the page content by default in every web browser. The scrollbar only appear inside the scroll bar area if content extends beyond 100% height of the viewport. This allows your page width, and any margins or paddings to be calculated by the browser beforehand and stop the pages from shifting as users view pages that scroll and those that do not. I use this trick often as it sets the page width perfectly for all scenarios and your web pages will never shift and load lightning fast!

I believe `height:auto` is the default on `body` in most UA browser style sheets. So understand most browsers default to that value, anyway.

Adding `min-height:100%` gives you the default height you want `body` to have and then allows the page dimensions to fill the viewport without content breaking out of the body. This works only because `html` has derived its 100% height based on the viewport.

The two CRITICAL pieces here are not the units, like `%` or `vh`, but making sure the root element, or `html`, is set to 100% of the viewport height. Second, its important that body have a `min-height:100%` or `min-height:100vh` so it starts out filling the viewport height, whatever that may be. Nothing else beyond that is needed.

STYLING HEIGHT FOR LEGACY BROWSERS

Notice I have added "fallback" properties for `height` and `min-height`, as many browsers pre-2010 do not support "vh" viewport units. It's fun to pretend everyone in the web world uses the latest and greatest but the reality is many legacy browsers are still around today in big corporate networks and many still use antiquated browsers that do not understand those new units. One of the things we forget is many very old browsers do not know how to fill the the viewport height correctly. Sadly, those legacy browsers simply had to have `height:100%` on both the `html` element and the `body` as by default they both collapsed height by default. If you did not do that, browser background colors and other weird visuals would flow up under content that did not fill the viewport. The example above should solve all that for you and still work in newer browsers.

Before modern HTML5 browsers (post-2010) we solved that by simply setting `height:100%` on both the `html` and `body` selectors, or just `min-height:100%` on the `body`. So either solution allows the code above to work in over 20+ years of legacy web browsers rather than a few created the past couple of years. In old Netscape 4 series or IE 4-5, using `min-height:100%` instead of `height:100%` on the body selector could still cause height to collapse in those very old browsers and cause text to overflow background colors. But that would be the one issue I could see with this solution.

**Using my CSS solution, you now allow your website to be viewed correctly in 99.99% of browsers, past and present** rather than just 60%-80% of browsers built the past few years.

Good Luck!

Comment: This is the most perfect solution ever seen!

Comment: It is cool, but... issue is complex, and one for all solution does not exist. Just to mention one important consideration, currently we have svh (small viewport height) and lvl (large viewport height) which resolves challenges on mobile with/without tools expanded. You need to control the state, not hope it will be self-resolved.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use JS if needed

```
var winHeight = window.innerHeight    || 
document.documentElement.clientHeight || 
document.body.clientHeight;

var pageHeight = $('body').height();
if (pageHeight < winHeight) {
    $('.main-content,').css('min-height',winHeight)
}
```

Comment: But for this you need to add more things than needed like jQuery library and  writing in JavaScript whilst this can be done in CSS.

Comment: @Front-endDeveloper This doesn't require jQuery, and unfortunately as of 2021 none of the CSS solutions handle the issue of browser chrome like bookmarks tabs as well as this simple JavaScript solution does. There's a time and place for scripting, and this is it.

Answer (score 6):

Here:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
}

body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0
  background:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use this

```css
html, body{
      background: #E73;
      min-height: 100%;
      min-height: 100vh;
      overflow: auto; // <- this is needed when you resize the screen
    }
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

The browser will use `min-height: 100vh` and if somehow the browser is a little older the `min-height: 100%` will be the fallback.

The `overflow: auto` is necessary if you want the body and html to expand their height when you resize the screen (to a mobile size for example)

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<html style="width:100%; height:100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<body style="overflow:hidden; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;">
```

Comment: Could you explain please, what is the possible purpose of `width: 100%` for body and html elements? Yes, I understand, that from practical point of view, `body { margin: 0; }` should be enough in most cases. I just want to understand more thoroughly.

Answer (score 3):

Please check this:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}    
html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%;}
```

Or try new method Viewport height :

```
html, body { width: 100vw; height: 100vh;}
```

Viewport:
If your using viewport means whatever size screen content will come full height fo the screen.

Comment: Please include an explanation of your solution so others who find this answer can understand. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain please, what is the possible purpose of `width: 100%` for body and html elements?

Comment: so lets say i have a table with 50 columns and 1000 rows having numbers between 1000 to 9999, what will happen to them, will they scroll beyond the window like we do normally or will they have an overflow type scrollbar

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want the work of editing your own CSS file and define the height rules by yourself, the most typical CSS frameworks also solve this issue with the body element filling the entirety of the page, among other issues, at ease with multiple sizes of viewports.

For example, [Tacit](https://github.com/yegor256/tacit) CSS framework solves this issue out of the box, where you don't need to define any CSS rules and classes and you just include the CSS file in your HTML.

Answer (score 3):

For the true purists, this one respects the default margins of the browser, and prevents the undesired scroll generated by the other methods, besides growing if the content grows. Tested in Chrome, Safari and Firefox. The backgrounds are just for show...

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
body {
  flex:1;
  background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
html {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 100%;
}
html body {
    min-height: 100%
}
```

Works for all major browsers: FF, Chrome, Opera, IE9+. Works with Background images and gradients. Scrollbars are available as content needs.

Answer (score 1):

Only with 1 line of CSS… You can get this done.

```
body{ height: 100vh; }
```

Comment: Watch out for this. `100vh` is actually [not what you expect for iOS Safari.](https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html)

Answer (score 1):

all answers are 100% correct and well explained,
but i did something good and very simple to make it responsive.

here the element will take 100% height of view port but when it comes to mobile view it don't look good specially on portrait view ( mobile ), so when view port is getting smaller the element will collapse and overlap on each other. so to make it little responsive here is code.
hope someone will get help from this.

```
<style>
.img_wrap{
      width:100%;
      background: #777;
}
.img_wrap img{
      display: block;  
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 50px 0px;
      margin: 0 auto;
}
.img_wrap img:nth-child(2){
      padding-top: 0;
}
</style>

<div class="img_wrap">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/84/fc/7184fc63db0516a00e7d86900d957925.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/71/84/fc/7184fc63db0516a00e7d86900d957925.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<script>
   var windowHeight = $(window).height();
   var elementHeight = $('.img_wrap').height();

   if( elementHeight > windowHeight ){
       $('.img_wrap').css({height:elementHeight});
   }else{
       $('.img_wrap').css({height:windowHeight});
   }
</script>
```

here is [JSfiddle Demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/wasimv09/t2q5um63/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I style the div container - usually the sole child of the body with the following css

```
.body-container {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: It's crazy how far down flex box is. This is what I use on my projects and it works well in frameworks like react or vue

Answer (score 1):

Over 20 answers later and none seem to have mentioned the factor that I found was the most crucial - the markup.

After trying basically every answer in this question and a few others, I restructured my markup to something like the following:

```
<body>
  <div class="section1">
    <nav>
    </nav>
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="section2">
  </div>
</body>
```

Essentially, it requires two different outer containers. The first container is for the purpose of containing the navbar *and* extending the background colour/image all the way to the height of the browser, and the second one for  containing everything "below the fold" - including the second background colour/image.

**This solution allows the first container's background to expand all the way to the bottom while keeping the second container free to take up as much space as it needs.**

From this point on, the only CSS needed to get the result both I and the original question wanted is the following:

```
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.section1 {
  height: 100%;
  background: black; /* for demo purposes */
}

.section2 {
  background: white; /* for demo purposes */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here Update**

```
html
  {
    height:100%;
  }

body{
     min-height: 100%;
     position:absolute;
     margin:0;
     padding:0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now there is newer way supported by all modern browsers. Simply use:

```css
.el {
  height: -moz-available;
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
  height: stretch;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

About the extra space at the bottom: is your page an ASP.NET application? If so, there is probably a  wrapping almost everything in your markup. Don't forget to style the form as well. Adding `overflow:hidden;` to the form might remove the extra space at the bottom.

Comment: I do not recommend using overflow:hidden unless you have a really good reason. Find out why things are overflowing and adjust so it will not overflow instead

Answer (score -8):

CSS3 has a new method.

```
 height:100vh
```

It makes ViewPort 100% equal to the height.

So your Code should be

```
 body{
 height:100vh; 
 }
```

Comment: How is this different than [**the answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25829844/2680216) I posted a year ago in September?

Comment: why you double answer?