# Parent DIV with min-height and child with percentage height doesn't working

Tags: css, height

Im experincing some problems with a min-height on a div and its children height.
I know what is happening but I don't know how to solve it.

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<img src="#"/>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And the stylesheet:

```
#container { min-height:180px; max-height:20%;}
#container img { height:60%;}
#container ul { height:40%; padding:10px;}
#container ul li { height:100%; float:left;}
```

What I'm trying is to apply to the UL, the 40% of the parent. What I get is that the UL is getting the window's height, not its parent.
If I put just a max-height or a fixed height, it works.

I supose the problem cames by the time the items are created or something like that, but i'm not sure cause the IMG takes its parent's height

Any solution?

I think that finally I'm getting close to the solution thanks to @Jay-Bee-Why, but I didn't get it.

Case 1-
container has height:180px and max-height:20%
Then the container flows, and its children to the max-height, but there is no limit on the minimum so, the problem is not solved

Case 2-
container has min-height, height, and max-height
Here only min-height is working.For example:
    #container { min-height:100px; height:180px; max-height:20%}
Here container's height varies from 100px to 180px. max-height is omitted.

As I explain on the comments, the point I'm looking for is a DIV with a variable height from 180px to 20% of window browser's height wich contains two items. An IMG, with 60% of his parent height, and a UL with 40% inside it, there is a floating LI with 100% of their parent height.

Answer (score 0):

You should include more detail in your question, including a working image. But take a look at my [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/hkrYc/) and you'll see a few possible explanations.

1. You're applying `height:100%` to each of your `li` elements. That means each `li` is as tall as its parent element, the `ul`. So right now the content inside the `ul` is 4x the height of the `ul` itself, since you have four `li` in there each the size of the `ul`. In [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkrYc/) you can see the bullet points overflowing their parent.
2. Percentage-based heights (or widths) are based off parent heights. The only height that you've specified in your document is `min-height:180px`. You'll notice in [my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkrYc/) that your desired percentage-based layout wasn't achieved until I applied an actual height (not a minimum height) to the parent container. Without an actual height value besides `height:auto`, the browser isn't sure how to calculate the percentage-based height. I should note that this is not the case with width. If you specify only percentages for element width, the browser knows to base its calculations off the browser window.

Comment: It looks like you changed your code to include `float:left` after I wrote this answer. Include a screenshot or something of the problem you're experiencing, or the actual code, since it's hard to understand the problem or what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, If I didn't included enough details, I usually describe too much and I thought it will confuse people.

Comment: I forgot to transcribe from my original code that LI are floating left.
I've working with your fiddle to find a clue.

Im trying to make the following:
#container has to be from 180px to 20% of window's height. (I'm trying to put this top on the bottom for small screen sizes).
IMG has to be 60% of #container.
UL has to be the 40% of #container completing it.

If I put a fixed height you are right, IMG and UL uses their parent height to be created, but the main problem is not fixed

Comment: Try adding this to the top of your stylesheet then:

`html, body {
    height:100%;
}`

Now, the parent of `#container`, which is either `html` or `body` depending on the browser, has a height that its children can base itself off of.

Refer here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473162/how-do-i-set-height-of-container-div-to-100-of-window-height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473162/how-do-i-set-height-of-container-div-to-100-of-window-height)

Comment: Sorry, It keeps doing the same.
If I put a fixed height to #container, both children use it to get properties, but if I try to use min and max-height, just IMG use its parent to get the propper size. The UL keeps using window height to do it, even when UL and IMG are at the same level.