# Fitting the page to the screen

Tags: html, css

I'm using this following code:

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left:  30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
}
```

Everything is good from the top and sideways but the page doesn't reach to the bottom. How can I get it to reach all the way to the bottom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `height: 100%;`

http://jsfiddle.net/uTG2R/

**EDIT:**

It appeared that it wasn't only the html and body that needed to have their height set, but the table within was the actual culprit. By defining the height of the html and body tags we could then set the defined height of the table tag.

Comment: Do you have more CSS and HTML code that we can see to further investigate the problem? Or perhaps create your example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Add the height: 100% to your html, body and table. I believe you're wanting to expand the table element, but in order for you to be able to use height: 100% on the table you must first put height:100% on the html and body.

Comment: check again..still not...some wierd thing...
@Chase

Comment: Hmm, well for one you may want to remove the overflow:hidden so that the end of the table isn't cut off.

Comment: perfect ! alil fixin it if u notice..there is stll alil small scrolling that can be done..i dont want that
@Chase

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that as well. I beleive it's due to the margins, so try making the body and table height 95% or so..

Comment: Any time. It helped a lot being able to see the code, so thank you for that. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try this in CSS

```
body {
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        margin-right: 30px;
        margin-left:  30px;
        margin-top: 40px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
         background-color: gray;
         height: 100%;
        }
        html, table
        {
            height:100%;
        }
```

Please correct your code at `<body style="">` remove `style=""`. it should be `<body>`
[Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

> Body looks to its parent (HTML) for how to scale the dynamic property,
>   so HTML needs to be set too.

Comment: @Ori Gavriel Refael: Then you can set `height:90%`.

Answer (score 0):

Add height: 100%; to your css. This should do what you require.

Comment: Try adding overflow: hidden; to it also.

Answer (score 0):

By the provided link [84.229.230.105:8080/NiceTry2/MyServlet](http://84.229.230.105:8080/NiceTry2/MyServlet), what you need is additionally to the body height, set also the height to 100% on the HTML tag.

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

---

**EDITED:**

Just builded a Fiddle with a more accurate sample to solve the problem you are having without causing another one:

The Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/u7HAe/)!

Since the solution of 100% to stretch the body all the way down does solve the issue, the margin at the top and bottom of the body tag causes a certain overflow of the body tag, since 100% + 40px + 40px is always bigger than 100% :)

The Fiddle suggests that the HTML and BODY tags have 100% x 100% of the view port size, and using one absolutely positioned div to wrap the entirely page content. The mentioned wrapper gets the required margins.

Comment: only in html alone it doesnt help, but added table to it, now it expands all the page too 100% ignoring the Bottom Mergin that i wrote before.
@zuul

Comment: @Ori Gavriel Refael, just edited the answer with a solution to that particular problem :)

Comment: One question! Do you also want the table all the way down? and all the way to the right?