# HTML height 100 % causes page overflow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an html page with 2 divs : "top" and "main"

The top `<div>` must take the place of its contained elements, the main `<div>` must take all the remaining place.

Here is what I tried:

**CSS CODE :**

```
html,body{
  height:100%;
}

#top{
  background-color : red;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid;
}

#main{
  background-color : blue;
  height:100%;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid;
}

#content1{
  background-color:yellow;
}

#content2{
  background-color:yellow;
  height :100%;
}
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <div id="top">
      <div id="content1">content1</div>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <div id="content2">content2</div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cEdq/)

As you can see, the "100%" I set on "content2" causes this div to take 100% of the page height instead of just the remaining space. Is there a magic css property to fix this?

**EDIT:**

Thank you for all your solutions.

I finally chose the solution proposed by Riccardo Pasianotto based on CSS properties `display:table` and `display:table-row`.

Here is my final **HTML CODE**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
  <div id="content1" class="row">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div class="subContentContainer">
         content1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content2" class="row">
    <div class="subcontent">
      <div class="subContentContainer">
        content2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
</body>
```

Here is the corresponding **CSS CODE**:

```
html,body{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

body{
  display:table;
}

.row{
  display:table-row;
  width:100%;
}

#top{
  height:100px;
}

#content1{
  background:#aa5555;
  padding:10px;
}

#content2{
  background:#5555AA;
  height:100%;
}

.subcontent{
  padding : 10px;
  height:100%;
}

.subContentContainer{
  background-color:yellow;
  height:100%;
}
```

And here is the corresponding [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b2X4r/3/).

Comment: Why would you like to have your main content stick to the bottom ? Maybe you would like to have a footer at the bottom of the page ?

Comment: You are missing the DOCTYPE in your HTML.

Comment: Later, I will put a border around the yellow zones. Then, If the height of the main content is bigger as the zone, I will put scroll bars. For the user, I think that it's cleaner if the size of this zone never changes.

Comment: @w4rumy for the sake of simplicity, I did not put it in this example. Is this important in this particular case?

Comment: Doctypes are allways important. but in jsfiddle is isn't needed.

Comment: I thought jsfiddle automatically generates the html tag.Adenoyelle,do you want something exactly like content1?

Comment: jsfiddle is indeed implementing the <html> and doctype attributes automatically.

Comment: "content1" is just a placeholder. Later, there will be another content  which height can change over time. That's why it would be hard to hardcode the height.

Comment: You could do this using a bit of jquery. Using your viewport.   `$(document).ready(function(){
      resizeDiv();
  });

  window.onresize = function(event) {
      resizeDiv();
  }

  function resizeDiv() {
      vpw = $(window).width(); 
      vph = $(window).height(); 
      $('#somediv').css({'height': vph + 'px'});
  }`

Comment: @adenoyelle Missing DOCTYPE means your browser goes into Quirks mode and renders elements differently. Therefore, if anything is not working and the example is missing a DOCTYPE, we are working based on a non-standard HTML document. So I always suggest adding a DOCTYPE first - experience has shown that a lot of bugs disappear then.

Comment: @w4rumy This does not solve the problem but effectively makes a difference. With `<!DOCTYPE html>`, the height of `<html>` and `<body>` are not `100% anymore`. I added the doctype and specified explicitly those heights. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMOJF](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/5cEdq/28/)**

For doing this you have to use `display:table` so edit in that way

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}
#top {
  height: 100px;
}
#content1 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
#content2 {
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="top" class="row">
    <div id="content1">content1</div>
  </div>

  <div id="main" class="row">
    <div id="content2">content2</div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Starting from your example, I could adapt it to do exactly what I wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/b2X4r/

Answer (score 1):

What I often do is making a container without padding to `min-height: 100%` and let my content have its proper height (auto) :

This will make something like this :

```
#container {
    background-color : #5555AA;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#content2 {
    background-color:yellow;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5cEdq/25/

I don't know if this is exactly what you want, but you can't make a div just "fill the remaning space" without making it absolute. What you don't really want either.

Comment: There aren't any better ways of doing this I guess. so this could be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/5cEdq/16/

**CSS :**

```
   html,body{
      height:100%;
      Padding:0; 
      margin:0;
      border:0;}
```

Comment: The rendering is not correct with both browsers I tried (Chrome and FF on Linux). Is this correct with your browser?

Comment: @MrLister: Sorry. I am wrong. I tired setting height for body (I wanted to create an application with footer). But now I see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a magic css property to fix this?

Yes there is. It's called `box-sizing`

Read [this article](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) for more info about the box-sizing property.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/wQnXU/)**

So if your header was say 64px high, then you'd do something like this:

```css
 .container {
   height: 100%;
   background: pink;
   margin-top: -64px;
   padding-top: 64px;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    content here
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both Divs are using 100% height set on the html and body tag you only need to set it there then zero your margin and padding. Generally if you have to set a div and its parent div both to 100% height you're overdoing it.