# Height more than 100% of browser height

Tags: html, css

I'm building responsive webiste. I don't want to set a default height in px, but I want to to something like this. This will be only top of layout. E.g. [prowly.com](http://prowly.com).

[image]

And my fiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/QVxW8/1/

```
        html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
        }
        div#handler {
            width: 100%;
            height: 110%;
            display:block;
        }
        div#content {
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;
            background: red;
        }
        div#content2 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            background: blue;
        }
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="handler">
        <div id="content">I want to 100% height of browser</div>
        <div id="content2">I want 10% of height browser</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Ps. As I also saw, 100% of height it's buggy on Safari iPhone and Opera Mobile so I don't know what should I do. Of course I can use JS but I want to know is there other way?

Comment: No bug. It's supposed to be that way.

Comment: try position:absolute; on #handler

Comment: Also, it's been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set body like this

```
html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding:0;
                position:absolute;/* this is very important*/
                bottom:0;
                top:0;
                right:0;
                left:0;
            }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QVxW8/5/

or like this:

```
html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding:0;
                position:absolute;/* this is very important*/
                left:0;
                top:0;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
```

and to have the correct values use

```
*{
margin:0;
padding:0;
-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

or just change you code to

```
html, body {
                margin: 0;
                padding:0;
                height:100%;
            }
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QVxW8/6/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding 100% height in the `html, body` like so :

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
    }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QVxW8/3/)

EDIT : You may want to read [this](http://somacss.com/fullheight.html) article.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
*{padding: 0; marign:0;}
      html, body {
            margin: 0;
            padding:0;
        }
        div#handler {
            width: 100%;
            height: 110%;
            display:block;
        }
        div#content {
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;
            background: red;
        }
        div#content2 {
            width: 100%;
            height: 10%;
            background: blue;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding:0;
    }
    div#handler {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        display:block;
    }
    div#content {
        width: 100%;
        height:90%;
        background: red;
    }
    div#content2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        background: blue;
    }
```

**the trick here is use VH for device height or VW for device width instead of % or px**