# fit wrapper to 100% width and height

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a `div` which fits the full height and width of the browser viewport. I just thought about simple css like:

```
#wrapper { width: 100%;
           height: 100%;
           background-color: red;
}
```

but it  does not work for the height. The `#wrapper` does not have any height. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to add `height: 100%;` to the `<html>` and `<body>` elements as well

Comment: The question has already been answered here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height

Comment: you need to set position: absolute;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/zDuWh/

or

```
html, body { height: 100% }

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/VJv6h/

Comment: exactly what I needed. But could you explain why I have to declare the height in the body and htmls css and the width not?

Comment: @supersize Sure! A `div` per default a block-element (`display:block`) if your set `display` to `inline` for example this will not work anymore. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display and here: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-box/#display

Answer (score 1):

How about this:-

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

or

```
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100% }
```