# Android WebBrowser scroll down page

Tags: android, html, delphi, delphi-xe5

I developed an android app with `Delphi XE 5` and I put a WebBrowser because I must show a webpage. By the way (the webpage) has a width of 1400px and so it is not entirely displayed.

[image]

The width is fixed because I used on the webpage `width:100%`, but as you can see on the picture, I only have a part of the table. I am missing a scroll bar that allows me to slide down the page and look at the rest of the table.

I tried to add a `TVertScrollBox` and inside it I put the WebBrowser but I still see only the beginning of the page. I cannot scroll it down.

How could I fix this? The webpage already have a `div` with a scroll bar on the left. You can click [here](http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/european_mobile.html) to see the entire page.

Comment: What happens if you open this page with your build-in Android web browser?

Comment: I opened it with Firefox for android and I can scroll the page

Comment: try setting the body/html tag height/min-height to 100% too. this is obviously an HTML issue.

Comment: I've setted on this page (http://mk7vrlist.altervista.org/databases/american_mobile.html) html{height: 100%;} body {min-height: 100%;} but it still doesn't work.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height

Comment: Why Firefox? Surely that's not behind the android web browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't set any property on `WebBrowser`, I only put this code on my webpage:

```
body { 
  min-height: 100%;  
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

In this way, I can scroll down the page displayed on my WebBrowser.