# CSS body 100% height and overflow when necessary

Tags: javascript, html, css, height

I know how to ensure that the HTML body vertically stretches/shrinks to 100% height of the browser viewport (by having 100% height in the body and html rules).

I also know that normal HTML flow will result in containers vertically stretching to contain their contents (if things are set up properly).

Yet, I cannot seem to achieve both.

I.e. I cannot beat CSS into ensuring that when my page is viewed on a high resolution screen that it vertically stretches to leave no gaps AND to ensure that if my page is viewed on a lower resolution screen that the body stretches past the viewport (to accommodate all the content) and introduces scrollbars.

To me that is ideal behaviour and yet I sadly believe that this cannot be achieved purely in CSS. I know I can do this in JavaScript quite easily, but I want to be able to do it just in CSS.

Is it possible, or am I forced to use JavaScript?

**Edit**:
I have researched, tried and test so many techniques, but it just seems like it can't be done. Looks like I am going to have to go back to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so this definitely works for me:

```
html {
   height: 100%;
}

body {
   min-height: 100%;
   display: flex;
}

#wrapper {
   width: 100%; /* Necessary because of side-effect of flex */
   height: 100%;
}
```

Exactly what I tried before, but I thought I would give this new CSS feature "flex" a go and it has done the trick. So it looks the CSS managers/creators have finally addressed these critical issues with dynamic height and vertical centring.

I hope this helps someone else stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [min-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-height) css property.

```
html, body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This seems to stretch the html entity to the size of the viewport (good), but unfortunately the body does not stretch as well. I tried making html have min-height 100% and body 100%, but that gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
min-height: 100%; /* other browsers */
height: auto !important; /* other browsers */
height: 100%; /* IE6: treated as min-height*/
```

Comment: Which rule/element should I apply these too? I tried html by itself and html and body; neither seem to work.

Comment: your need use html,body

Answer (score 0):

Taking inspiration from a question which seems to be pretty much the same as mine: [Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height?rq=1)

This is working for me:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Argghhh this doesn't work either, because then the containers inside body cannot be vertically stretched via percentage heights because CSS states that height only works if the parent has a fixed height (i.e. body cannot have min-height, but needs height). So... back to square one.