# Make html column extend all the way down without breaking layout

Tags: html, css

I have this layout: 
http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/BN9KJ/2/

It works by having an optional left column. How can I get the column colour extend all the way down the page even if there isn't enough content to fill it.

I was thinking it would be something like this:

```
height: auto;
```

But that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The Logic:** setting the height of the body,html element,because it is the parent element..!!

**BUT** why should we give both html and body --> height:100% ??
the answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/6654996/2967572

> Body looks to its parent (HTML) for how to scale the dynamic property,
>   so the HTML element needs to have it's height set as well.

just give

```
#left_column {
    width: 250px;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
  height:100%;  //added

}
```

along with

```
html,body{

    height:100%;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cE4a8/)

**BUT**

> However the content of body will probably need to change dynamically.
>   Setting min-height to 100% will accomplish this goal.

it will be good alternative to give `min-height`

```
  #left_column {
        width: 250px;
        background-color: orange;
        float: left;
      min-height:100%;  //added

    }
```

[**DEMO with Min-height**](http://jsfiddle.net/4JbCK/)

Answer (score 2):

add the following css

```
html,body{
height:100%;
}
```

and then apply `height: 100%` for the divs

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BN9KJ/4/)