# How to force Form tag in aspx pages to have min-height 100%

Tags: html, css

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

I want my Footer to be aligned to bottom of browser if there is not enough data on page.Above code works for HTML and body but it fails for form tag in ASPX pages ([as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)). How can we force form tag to have 100% height? adding bellow is not working.

```
body, form {
      min-height: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**Look at here may solve your problem and get you the understanding of min-height**

AND [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mohalibala/L9GEa/56/)

The CSS

```
    .maindiv {
    overflow:hidden; border:#000 1px solid;
    /*changes*/
     height:100%;
   }
.left_inner {
    min-height:100%; background:#00CC33;
    /*changes*/
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}/*changes*/
html,
body{
    height:100%;
}
.footer
{
 background:red;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="maindiv">
    <div class="left_inner">Left Block content</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```