# CSS linear gradient appears as alternate lines of different colors

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a linear gradient of 2 colours but it is not working and instead showing me alternate lines of different colors as seen in the image

[image: This is the screenshot from jsfiddle]

I am using this css

```
body{ background: linear-gradient(white, rgb(221,221,221));}
```

This is the complete [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxzeroedge/78cx3/)

Comment: You may want to use a tool like this one: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 2):

Just add `height:768px;` in css .

http://jsfiddle.net/arshidkv12/78cx3/1/

Comment: What will happen if the height of the page goes beyond 768px?

Comment: Defining height. Or body is splitting, if you are not define .

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

and will work.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aWyv)

Comment: height: 100% doesn't work. Atleast not in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxzeroedge/78cx3/2/)

Comment: Yes, it works, i guess you put it at body and should be `html, body` not body alone. I've put a jsfiddle.

Comment: ok, yeah, it does. But why do I need to have html and body together?
Also, how can I get rid of the whitespace at bottom?

Comment: Here's the explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height

Comment: Updated fiddle. White space at bottom can be removed using maring and padding in same selector, updated the jsfiddle to acomplish.