# Why is css height not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I try to set the height of an element I can't get it working. I have tried doing it with css and jquery but both without result.

This is the css I tried:

```
#slider{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-image: url(/img/background.jpg);
 background-size: 100%;
}
```

and this the Jquery code

```
var screen_height = $(document).height();
$('#slider').css('Height', screen_height );
```

does somebody know how to fix this. This is not the first time I have this problem and normally I can fix it with Jquery but now even that doesn't work.

Comment: lowercase --> $('#slider').css('height', screen_height ); and maybe you need to add 'px' like so: $('#slider').css('height', screen_height+'px' );

Comment: Have you included the css or js file correctly ?

Comment: Just make it like this $('#slider').height( $(window).height() );

Comment: Is, by any chance, `#slider {}` in `Home.css`?

Comment: all files are included correctly and $('#slider').height( $(window).height() ); doesn't work.

Comment: you may create a http://jsfiddle.net for us

Comment: You need to set 100% height for html and body - [Like this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6654996/2930477). `html{
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}`

Comment: Yes, it does. http://jsfiddle.net/zyenyw5z/

Comment: @Vinc199789 Make a fiddle because everything we told you is working, so you must have another issue going on :)

Comment: @Vinc199789 And why do you have the meta tag inside your #page div?

Comment: that is from an included file

Comment: So you are loading another file inside #page? With jQuery load?

Comment: yes and the site is a little bit to complicated to create a jsfiddle

Comment: What does the console log say? The jQuery code you tried and the jQuery suggestions people have been giving you all work, so there is something else that is wrong. Are you sure you're including jQuery before executing the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you are inserting another page into #page you need to add the height of the slider when the loading is complete.

```
$( "#page" ).load( "content.php", function() {
    $('#slider').height( $(window).height() );
});
```

Or like this

```
$( "#page" ).load( "content.php", function() {
    $('body').find('#slider').height( $(window).height() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
var screen_height = $(document).height();
$('#slider').css('height', screen_height );
```

or

```
$('#slider').height(screen_height );
```

Answer (score 0):

For `height: 100%;` to work in `#slider`, you must also have an explicit height set in its parent. Or, have relative height set in all ancestors all the way up to and including `html` or an ancestor with explicit height set.

Answer (score 0):

Use this  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ouoqjjLy/1/)

```
var screen_height = $(document).height();
$('#slider').css({height: screen_height});
```

Comment: You don't need 'px' :)

Comment: You don't need {} if there is just one css statement

Comment: @caramba no you don't but this way is more familiar to pure css and you don't need to remember `.height` ...