# CSS background color height 100% not working

Tags: html, css

I have a div like so:

```
<div class="background"></div>
```

and I am trying to give it 100% height so the background color is the whole div. Here is my CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  background-color: #1D3862;
  clear: both;
  height: 100%;
}
```

but its not working...what can I do to fix this ?

Comment: seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/1bz91jfp/1/

Comment: What isn't working? It works, but you can put background directly to `body` without need of extra `div`.

Comment: If there are any more elements, then they may push it down, maybe you have to give it absolute position

Comment: be sure all the parents of `.background`till`body`also have `height:100%`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the default margin from the body

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.background {
  background-color: #1D3862;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```