# 100% height div container not working with header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

See http://jsfiddle.net/oedev/pag7ahz2/

I have the following page layout:

- cMain - main page container
- cBanner - banner container
- cNavigation - navigation container
- cContent - page content container

All these are sized at 100%, as I want the page content to be sized at 100% (apart from the banner).

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

#cMain {
    height: 100%;
}

#cBanner {
    background: #002d62 top center no-repeat scroll;  
    height: 200px; 
    margin-bottom: 1em; 
    margin-top: 1em;    
}

#cContent {
    height: 100%
}
```

I have set the height of the html, body and containing divs to 100%.

However, as I have a header logo and navbar, the div under these is not being sized at 100% (I'm ending up with a scroll bar).

If I remove the header and nav bar divs, the content div is sized @ 100% with no scroll bars.

Comment: hi i think you need to apply **height:auto ** to html,body instead of  **100%**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height from the body tag.

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Or set an min height for the body as shown in this post: [Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

```
html {
    height: 100%
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the 100% height on the html tag works to an extent, in that it removes the scroll bars. Within my content container div, I host a Kendo ui grid, which includes paging controls. If I expand the size of my window, I would expect these to shift to the bottom of my window. This is not happening. Based on this example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dimodi/SDFsz/