# Keeping a div at full height when it doesn't fit in viewport

Tags: html, css

My goal is a centered content wrapper which extends to the full height of the page at any time. So far my CSS works if all the content fits into the viewport, but if it doesn't then the div stops after the initial viewport height.

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

div {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #FAA
}
```

demo 1: https://jsfiddle.net/86j3qshr/1/

If you leave out the weight attribute at the div tag then it works as long as the content overflows the viewport. Otherwise the div isn't at full viewport height.

demo 2: https://jsfiddle.net/86j3qshr/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `min-height` property rather than the `height` property.

When you set `height: 100%` on the element with the background, it will have a height of `100%` of the parent element. Since the parent element's height is equal to the height of the viewport, it won't work as expected. Since you don't want the element's maximum `height` to be the same as the viewport, a `min-height` work better.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/jm5rwb1v/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As a side note, you can also use [viewport-percentage units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height/25829844#25829844):

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/j94www0m/)

```
div {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```