# 2 Divs with position fixed and absolute with top 0

Tags: css

I am using this CSS:

```
html{
height:100%;
}

#Nav{
position:fixed;
top:0;
}

#Heading{
position:absolute;
top:0;
}
```

The problem is that when using the DIV #Heading in the HTML file, it will cause a scrollbar.

So is it impossible to use two DIVs with "fixed" positioning and top 0?

When I remove the second div (position:absolute) the scrollbar disappears.

Could you tell me how to code the CSS correctly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish and why do you need to use `position`?

Comment: I need this for a fixed background scrolling site. On this site, the heading should overlap the first image shown. Like this in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWoOpJtkyjI thx!

Comment: I think I forgot to add overflow:hidden; to html

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: This is way too few information to give you an actual answer helping you.
Your CSS states no dimensions whatsoever for the fixed/absolute positioned elements.
An absolute positioned container exceeding the height of its ancestors (I assume `html` since its height is set to 100%) will cause a scrollbar to be shown.
I think you should learn basic HTML and CSS first before trying to do something like a section scroller.

Comment: The DIV does not really have a dimension, just a width of 100%; the nav is 1024 px wide. Is it somehow possible to remove the scrollbar?

Answer (score 0):

I've found hear a solution:

[Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

```
html { height:100%; }
body { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; right:0; left:0; }
```

The next problem is that I want to add a DIV with position: absolute to the bottom of the site, but this DIV is hanging in the middle of the page.