# Bootstrap/CSS - Keep footer at bottom even without enough content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this is a duplicate question, I've read through many questions on this particular question like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height).

But I can't for the life of me get mine to work.  I've tried many combinations of `height` and `min-height` for my `html` and `body`, using both % and vh.  I tried setting the margin to 0 as well but that doesn't help.  I tried this on both Chrome and Firefox, neither browser works.  There were some answers that suggested using `position: absolute` but that messes up the styling for all the content I have.

Some combos I tried:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

---

```
html{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

---

```
html{
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

My HTML layout:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ... stuff
    </head>
    <body class=".container">
        ... stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a fixed position for the bottom, but that can leave you with display problems as content gets covered.

I recommend using something like

```
body {
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

if you want to leave 100 px for your header and footer

Comment: Thank you.  This works for my laptop.  I'll have to test how responsive this method is on other devices.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is **[`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**, which tells the element to be fixed to that location, regardless of the other content. Couple this with **[`bottom: 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom)**, to state that the element should be fixed to the bottom of the page:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.container {
  background: #DDD;
  height: 50px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #DDD;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">Text</div>
  <div class="footer">Copyright</div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution :You can use the html 5 elements like 
Header,
Article,
Section,
Footer
And set there height and width according to your requirements...

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code to create a fixed footer at the bottom of your page

```
.yourfooterclass {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}
```

basically what this is doing is positioning the footer at the very bottom of the page, so it doesnt matter how much content you have on the page it will always be at the bottomn

Comment: I do not want the footer to be stuck on the bottom of the viewport.  I simply want the footer to be stuck to the bottom of the page; and if there is not enough content to fill the initial viewport, I still want the footer to be at the bottom

Comment: Yes, but when there is more content than the height of viewport, footer should be under this content, off screen.

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn't change anything on the `height`-property of the body, I found this solution at https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/[1](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-keep-your-footer-where-it-belongs-59c6aa05c59c/), also pure CSS:

**The html structure:**

```
<html>
 <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
 </head>

<body>
 <div id="page-container">
   <div id="content-wrap">
     <!-- all other page content -->
   </div>
   <footer id="footer"></footer>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**And the CSS accordingly:**

```
#page-container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#content-wrap {
  padding-bottom: 2.5rem;    /* Footer height */
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;            /* Footer height */
}
```