# css not setting divs to fit full screen

Tags: css

I have tried configuring css to fit panel-body to full screen, but no matter what I do it does not fit to full screen.

Please find the [JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/43ebfupd/) here.

Even tried to put class level css :

```
#apexBody {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

The footer here is fixed and I want the panel or the text area to fit the full screen till the footer.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=div+height+100%25+not+full+100%25+browser+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set to parent element and  to its child.

```
.panel {
    height: 100vh;
}
. panel-body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
.panel-body {
   background-color: white;
   border-radius: 0px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ccc;
   width: 800px;
   height: 800px;

}
```

Comment: I dont want to set the width and height in px as it will fail in big screens

Comment: Try following this Link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height