# Difference for inner element height when setting body to height=100% and max-height=100%

Tags: html, css

Based on this post (and others):

[Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

It seems like it's reasonable to do this:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

in order to stretch the background to the entire viewport. but why is this

different from

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

?

Compare this:
https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/bGGBVQy
[image]

with this:
https://codepen.io/benrhere/pen/ExxNVGW
[image]

Specifically setting an inner div to height:100% seems only to work when we set height=100% on the body, but NOT when we set max-height=100%.

Comment: in the first codepen, the css of body is not `height: 100%;` it's `max-height: 100%;`
look at this:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G94BB9HVNKS4

and this

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G94BBUUCB8UG

Comment: min-height and height used with percentage are relative to Height ... so if there is no height defined, they won't work and will never consider min-height as reference

Comment: Apologies about the max/min height mixup. I've corrected the first codepen, but see the same results. So, are you saying I can't have a min-height=100% when the parent has a defined height of the entire viewport?

Comment: percentage on height,min-height,max-height uses the height of the parent as reference so if a child is using one of the three the parent need to have Height defined, not max-height or min-height