# Bootstrap h-100 applied to <html> or <body> tag?

Tags: bootstrap-4

In some cases, the Bootstrap class `h-100` is applied to the `<html>` element, and in some cases to the `<body>` element, and sometimes to both. For example, in the code **Sticky footer with fixed navbar**, https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/, the class `h-100` is applied to both the `<html>` and `<body>` element, for short

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="h-100">
<head>
...
</head>
<body class="d-flex flex-column h-100">
...
</body>
</html>
```

Are there any logic behind this, any rules to follow, when to address the `<html>` element, and when to address the `<body>` element?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make body have 100% of the browser height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

In general 100% height is required when the design requires full height.

As an example a typical situation is to position the footer on the bottom, regardless of the screen's height. While developing these design concepts, lacking 100% height shows clear issues when dealing with empty pages, where no content is generating height and as a result, the footer is stacked below the header.

Design concepts that introduce height requirements:

- fixed footer
- centered content vertically
- modal UI backdrop
- scrolling enhancements
- …

These concepts usually only affect the CSS of your website and require the functionality to be both on the html and body tag.

## Back to question

So the question remains, why only on the `<html />` or only the `<body />`?
My idea is it depends on certain JavaScript calculations.

Imagine you require the top position of an element => `document` object is used
Imagine you require to scroll to a certain position => `window` object is used

Both functionalities can work separately where `document` object finds elements in the `<body />` and `window` object finds properties on the `<html />` tag.

Not entirely certain it's split this way, but I can see someone adding `h-100` class to the html tag to fix a scrolling issue and someone else adding `h-100` to the body to fix an offset/position issue. In my opinion it's always better to introduce height 100% for both.