# Trying to set body width and height to 100% so I can work with percentages but it ends up masking all of my other elements

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I've never had this happen before and I can't understand why this is happening. I'm working in React. I basically have a parent component with its body's css:

```
body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%
}
```

That way I can work with percentages in my project. My child component has

```
#Navbar {
width: 100%;
height: 10%;
background-color: black;
}
```

But I cannot see the child component *except* if I set its position to absolute.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Maybe you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height).

Answer (score 1):

In CSS, `body` refers to document.body, not the the body of a component. I don't know that you can set width and height on document.body... it doesn't make any sense really, as body is the top visible element in the dom.

Setting height = 80% or width=90% or whatever makes sense for sizing an element that is within another element. But body has no parentNode as such.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with react but maybe try to set the #Navbar content property. This should work for vanilla CSS and I hope for React too:

```
#Navbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: black;
  content: ""
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Does your component have content ?

`.body` references the HTML's body not your component. You have to give it an id or className for it to work

I would also recommend to use the `<nav>` html node and simply do as it's semantically more correct

```css
nav {
   color: red;
   etc...
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-dust-8hsuw?file=/src/App.js)