# Background image css not scaling down properly

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an image as a background of my project insde the **body** component, but when I reduce the screen width the image doesn't overflow correctly. This is what I have now:

[image]

the css is:

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://phoenix-engineering.be/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/shutterstock_1113165392.png");
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-position: unset;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  min-width: 350px;
}
```

and when I resize the screen it results to this:

[image]

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you checked how large the `body` element itself is? (`height:100%` doesn't necessarily mean it will take up the whole window)

Comment: Hello DBS, no I havent, can you tell me how exactly to do that?

Comment: The easiest way to check in the dev tools would be to hover over the `<body>` in the DOM, it should highlight the element. If it's not taking up the whole window, you may need to adjust the `height` of `html` ([Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6654958/make-body-have-100-of-the-browser-height))

Comment: I just checked and it seems it doesnt highlight the whole window, but also when I hover over the html component it alsoe doesnt highlight the whole window, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Have a look at the question I linked in the previous comment, it covers basically every different solution to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `min-height:100vh`

```
body {
  //prev_styles

  min-height:100vh; <-
}
```