# white space after the footer, only in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

There seems to be random white space after the footer at the bottom of the site, but it only shows up in Firefox. The site pulls up fine in Safari and Chrome. When I try to use inspect element, the white space doesn't seem to fall under any tags. It doesn't seem tied to any footer tags either as removing them didn't change anything.

I'm using [Ryan Fait's Sticky Footer](http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/) solution for my footer. It seems to work fine on Chrome and Safari, but doesn't seem to work on Firefox.

You can test it at: http://www.edmhunters.com/martin-garrix/

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check my answer out. It is tested and works. If you follow exactly what I say it will work in no time. Tested Chrome and Firefox which means will work in Safari as well. Going to be honest and say I don't care about IE so if it doesn't work there just move on, but that is personal opinion.

Comment: @CayceK Thanks, it works perfectly. Don't care about IE, never have, never will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both answers already provided do not help the situation...

```
<span class="footer-copyright">
<strong>© EDM Hunters 2014</strong>
</span>
```

Is located in your footer its placement is wrong. It isn't showing like it is in Chrome.. You need to move your menu over to the left a bit. I'll provide css when I get the exact styles.

In `global.min.***.css` on line 12, remove all your css add:

```
bottom: -102px;
position: relative;
```

This should be for `.footer-copyright`. Do not use `overflow:hidden` because that is for someone who doesn't know what is happening. Now... Right this second I need to check in Chrome, but this should be fine. I'll fix edit in a minute if it is not.

Final edit:

To work in Chrome add with the two styles above:

```
display: block;
float: left;
```

Comment: For anyone who downvoted my answer if it is out of jealous angst please let me know as this is the correct answer and solves his problem in all browsers. If you're trying to use `overflow: hidden` and a solution you need to research css a little more.

Answer (score 3):

If you add

```
overflow:hidden
```

To the footer element, it seems to fix the problem in firefox. I got this idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470715/css-white-space-at-bottom-of-page-despite-having-both-min-height-and-height-tag), so it's probably the same or a similar issue (collapsing margins).

Comment: Cheers, this worked for me in Firefox 62 and Edge 42 (the issue did not exist in IE 11 nor Chrome 69) on a SquareSpace website. I've contacted SquareSpace to alert them, but no reply yet. For the other lost souls, this worked perfectly! +1

The accepted answer is unfortunately beyond the CSS I can edit in SquareSpace. :(

Answer (score -1):

This is an issue with clearfix on firefox since... forever. If you remove clearfix and add either `float:left; width:100%` or `overflow:hidden` to the footer, it should be good in all browsers.

---

Also, you don't really use the clearfix correctly. Instead of adding an empty element like `<div class="clearfix"></div>`, you should just add the class to the container of the floated elements:

```
<div class="clearfix">
  <div style="float:left"></div>
  <div style="float:right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: His clearfix works well enough. Correctly is in the eye of the beholder when it comes to css except when you try to use something like overflow:hidden on an element without attempting to discover the real problem...