# White space below HTML document in chrome

Tags: html, css

I have this page , its a simple page demo website :

[website-link](http://purplefront.net/whitebug/whitebug.html)

I am getting huge white space at the end of the page,I don't know why.My document successfully validates as an HTML5 document . also i came across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470715/css-white-space-at-bottom-of-page-despite-having-both-min-height-and-height-tag) and tried both remedies,but none worked.

One thing to be noted is that on the `HTML` and `Body` i have the following rules .

```
html,body{
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

i don't know if its the 100% height causing the issue , but i certainly can't take that out .

Comment: If it's any consolation, it works fine in Chrome on a Mac.

Comment: It is looking good in chrome on ubuntu. Which browser you are viewing?

Comment: @Gunaseelan chrome on windows 7.

Comment: @Gunaseelan it is a kind of a bug that appears and dissapears and then appears again .

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik Maybe it is because of `height:100%`

Comment: @Gunaseelan i seriously doubt that , but i cannot change that rule anyways . the bug is not showing now , and i don't know why again ! . Thanks though .

Comment: We are not forcing you to change that. Try that one also. If it solved your problem, then I think it is okay for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71243/discussion-between-gunaseelan-and-alexander-solonik).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing padding and margin, and set height and width to auto. It might solve your problem.

Also try padding-bottom: (some negative value) // It is not recommended.

FYI i did not see any white part on the bottom of the webpage on chrome (Mac).

add display:block; in css

Answer (score -1):

If I was doing this, I would remove the HTML from this. Then I would use the "Auto" term. This will form to what you have in the HTML. If you add something, it will automatically change, and vice verse. This is just my opinion as well, I wouldn't add the "padding" and "margin" since they're zero. This will just add length to your CSS. I hope this is what you were looking for!

```
body{
background: #fff;
height: Auto;
width: Auto;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

-Hoyt

Comment: ! sorry , i cannot touch that rule ! . I'll need some other solution .